# Regex to pull log lines from a log file

Tags: python, regex

I have a log file and I want to pull a specific log line from it.
I am not familiar with regex but have had limited success with the format below.
What regex should I use to find a log line with text '= START BACKUP DETAILS END ==' and  '= START BACKUP DETAILS END ='

```
06/11/2023 13:41 LocalFileCacheHashDb filterExisting, items contains 577 items
06/11/2023 13:41 LocalFileCacheHashDb < filterExisting(15)
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher =============== START BACKUP DETAILS ===============
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher startBackup called with 68
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher startBackup called with isScheduledSync = true
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher startBackup called with isApplicationForeground = false
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher =============== START BACKUP DETAILS END ===============
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpHelper prepareSyncData
06/11/2023 13:42 AssetScannerSdkManager getAndFilterPhotoVideoFolderItem, descriptionItemList contains 570 items
06/11/2023 13:42 AssetScannerSdkManager getLocalMusic, descriptionItemList contains 1 items
06/11/2023 13:42 AssetScannerSdkManager getLocalDocs, descriptionItemList contains 6 items
06/11/2023 13:42 AssetScannerSdkManager getAssets, isRestore = false, descriptionItemList contains 577 items
```

```py
import re
with open('cached_logs.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    text_file=text_file.read()
    pattern = r'([M-c])'
    matches = re.findall(pattern, text_file)
with open('cacheOut.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write('\n'.join(matches))
```

Comment: Regex is not required. You can just test each text line to check if a specific substring (eg **START BACKUP DETAILS**) is in the line using such as `if "START BACKUP DETAILS" in text_line:` and develop the logic to get the lines you want.

Comment: Why isn't this a Duplicate of 'How do I learn Regular Expressions'  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Python example using `re` ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NLw1sr/1)):

```py
import re

text = """\
06/11/2023 13:41 LocalFileCacheHashDb filterExisting, items contains 577 items
06/11/2023 13:41 LocalFileCacheHashDb < filterExisting(15)
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher =============== START BACKUP DETAILS ===============
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher startBackup called with 68
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher startBackup called with isScheduledSync = true
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher startBackup called with isApplicationForeground = false
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher =============== START BACKUP DETAILS END ===============
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpHelper prepareSyncData
06/11/2023 13:42 AssetScannerSdkManager getAndFilterPhotoVideoFolderItem, descriptionItemList contains 570 items
06/11/2023 13:42 AssetScannerSdkManager getLocalMusic, descriptionItemList contains 1 items
06/11/2023 13:42 AssetScannerSdkManager getLocalDocs, descriptionItemList contains 6 items
06/11/2023 13:42 AssetScannerSdkManager getAssets, isRestore = false, descriptionItemList contains 577 items
"""

pat = r"(?<=START BACKUP DETAILS ===============\n).*?(?=\s*^[^\n]+START BACKUP DETAILS END)"

for block in re.findall(pat, text, flags=re.S | re.M):
    print("-" * 80)
    print(block)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher startBackup called with 68
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher startBackup called with isScheduledSync = true
06/11/2023 13:41 BackUpLauncher startBackup called with isApplicationForeground = false
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to extract the printing details?

I am not good enough in Python yet so I will give you the general idea, and provide a simple awk implementation:

- go in the log file line by line
- when the script encounters a line with '= START BACKUP DETAILS =' : set printing to 1, but do not print that line.
- when the script encounters a line with '= START BACKUP DETAILS END =' : set printing to 0, and do not print that line.
- when 'printing' is set to '1' : print the corresponding line.

Basic awk implementation:

```
awk '
/= START BACKUP DETAILS =/ { printing=1 ; next }
/= START BACKUP DETAILS END =/ { printing=0 ; next }
( printing == 1 )
' < logfile
```

If you do want to see the 2 regex lines : remove the " next ".